# Normal approximation of Poisson distribution

Tags: approximation, statistics

I am fairly new to statistics. I am working on a list of items in stochastic vehicle routing problem with Poisson distribution and I need to do a normal approximation. I read a paper with the following formulation (image attached). I am not sure what I am missing in my algebraic skills but I can't get to the final equation. $$\begin{align}&\operatorname{Prob}\left\{z\ge\frac{c-\bar\mu}{\sqrt{\bar\mu}}\right\}=\alpha\\\implies&(c-\bar\mu)=z_{1-\alpha}\sqrt{\bar\mu}\\\implies&(c-\bar\mu)^2=\bar\mu z_{1-\alpha}^2\quad\text{which, after some algebra, yields}\end{align}\\\bar\mu=\frac{2c+z_{1-\alpha}^2-\sqrt{z_{1-\alpha}^4+4cz_{1-\alpha}^2}}2.$$

Comment: I know nothing about the context, but the last equation seems to be just derived with [quadratic formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_formula)

Comment: Please don't upload images of text, use MathJax.

Answer (score 3):

**Context Free Algebra.**
As pointed out by [xd y](https://or.stackexchange.com/users/4569/xd-y) in the [comments](https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/9438/normal-approximation-of-poisson-distribution#comment19990_9438), one way to derive this without context (i.e., understanding the Gaussian approximation to the Poisson) is just to apply the [quadratic formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_formula) to the expression you provide.

For notation simplicity, let $z_{1-\alpha} \equiv z$.

Expanding and factoring permit immediately give the target form:
$\begin{align}
(c-\bar \mu)^2 &=\bar\mu z^2 \\
\bar\mu^2 -2c\bar\mu -\mu z^2 +c^2 &= 0 \\
\bar\mu^2 + \bar\mu(-2c-z^2) + c^2 &=0 \tag{Target Form} \\
\end{align}$

All that remains is to apply the [quadratic formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_formula) and simplify:

$$
\bar \mu = \frac{-(-2c-z^2) \pm \sqrt{(-2c-z^2)^2-4c^2}}{2} \\
\bar \mu= \frac{2c+z^2 \pm \sqrt{4c^2+4cz^2+z^4-4c^2}}{2} \\
\bar \mu= \frac{2c+z^2 \pm \sqrt{z^4 +4cz^2}}{2} \quad \square\\
$$

**With Context:  Normal (Gaussian) approximation to the Poisson distribution.**
The ideas behind the equations in your question come from this approximation.

If $X \sim \text{Poisson}(\lambda)$ then
$$X \approx \text{Normal}(\mu = \lambda,\; \sigma = \sqrt{\lambda}) \tag{1}$$ for a sufficiently large $\lambda$ value. As $\lambda$ increases, the approximation gets better and better.

One way to understand this is a $\text{Poisson}(20)$ random variable is equivalent to adding up the results of 20 independent and identically distributed (i.i.d.) $\text{Poisson}(1)$ random variables. This permits invoking the hallowed [Central Limit Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_limit_theorem) which immediately results in Equation $(1)$.

<sub>Related:

On CrossValidated (Stats.SE): [Normal approximation to the Poisson distribution](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/83283/177387)</sub>